# NuGet: include .pdb files and exclude the "Content" folder

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I've incorporated the following line in the CI-build to **create a private NuGet package on each build**:

```
nuget pack C:\Projects\Test\Test.vbproj -OutputDirectory \\nas1\NuGet
```

The **AssemblyInfo is read** (including the **version number**) and a NuGet package is created.
I'd like the package to **include the .pdb files** and **not contain a "Content" folder** (so only the 'lib').

**How** can I **change the command** to do that?

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately, I don't think you'll be able to both exclude the content files *and* include the .pdb files while packing via the project.  You could do one or the other.

First, make a [nuspec](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference) file (the `nuget spec` command makes this quick) and put it in the same location as your project.  When you pack your project, NuGet.exe will treat the spec as a supplement to your project's info.

To eliminate the content folder, when packing a project that also has a .nuspec file, an empty `<files />` node in the spec will indicate that you don't want any content files, even if they exist in the project.

To include the debug files, add something like this to your spec:

```
  <files>
    <file src="bin\*.pdb" target="lib\net35\" />    
  </files>
```

but that would tell the tool that you *do* have content, and then it would add all the *other* files, as well.  You could, perhaps, make a [symbol package](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-symbol-package) for your project, instead.

Another option would be to build exclusively from the spec (`nuget pack Test.nuspec`), and specify exactly the files you want to include.  It's more time consuming, but it gives you complete control over the package's contents.

Comment: After giving this some more thought, I suppose it's technically possible to do this through the command line by including the .pdb through the spec (as above) and then using the -Exclude flag to omit file types that you don't want.  But you would have to exclude _every_ single file type that's not a dll or pdb that would be included in "content", which may or may not be practical for you.

For example, this would exclude config, xml, and transform files from the package (and include pdb files, since they're set in the .nuspec):

`nuget pack -Exclude **\*.config;**\*.xml;**\*.transform`

Comment: +1 for eliminating the content folder with an empty ```<files \>``` node.

Answer (score 1):

On the content files that you don't want to package, do you need them to have a Build Action of "Content" in your project (in the properties window of the file in Visual Studio, if that is your IDE)?

If it is acceptable to change the Build Action to "None" (or anything else), then it won't end up in the content folder.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works - if you don't mind including source files too.
To ignore the content files add such an empty node to your nuspec:

```
<files>
</files>
```

And then run:

```
nuget pack C:\Projects\Test\Test.vbproj -Symbols
nuget push  *.symbols.nupkg -Source \\nas1\NuGet
```

Comment: The empty <files/> solution is not working anymore for me.