# How can I exclude some views and folders from being included into the deployed ASP.NET MVC NuGet package?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package

I have a project written with `C#` on the top of ASP.NET MVC 5 framework using Visual Studio 2017. The project is running on .NET 4.7.2 framework.

I am trying to use `nuget.exe` to create a package for my project so I can install it into other projects.

I have a folder called `resources` which contains `.js` and `.css` files that I don't want to include into my package. I want to be able to exclude the entire `resources` folder. I also don't want to include all of my views, only views in the `Views/Home` folder should be included.

How can I exclude these files from being included in my packaged project?

I tried to follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec) by add exclusion on all the view then add the one I want. Follow is my current `.nuspec` file as you can see,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>....</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>...</title>
    <authors>...</authors>
    <owners>...</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>...</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
    <copyright>2019</copyright>
    <tags></tags>
  </metadata>  

   <files>

       <file src="**\*.*" exclude="**\*.designer.cs;**\*.csproj;**\*.pdb;**\*.user;**\*.vspscc;**\*.nuspec;libman.json;package.json;packages.config;Web.config;ApplicationInsights.config;public\**\*.*;Resource\**\*.*;bin\**\*.*;node_modules\**\*.*;obj\**\*.*;**\*.log;Views\**\*.*"/>
       <file src="Views\Home\**\*.cshtml" />

   </files>
</package>
```

**UPDATED**

I also tried adding the same rules into the `contentFiles` like so

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>....</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>...</title>
    <authors>...</authors>
    <owners>...</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>...</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
    <copyright>2019</copyright>
    <tags></tags>
    <contentFiles>
       <files include="**\*.*" exclude="**\*.designer.cs;**\*.csproj;**\*.pdb;**\*.user;**\*.vspscc;**\*.nuspec;libman.json;package.json;packages.config;Web.config;ApplicationInsights.config;public\**\*.*;Resource\**\*.*;bin\**\*.*;node_modules\**\*.*;obj\**\*.*;**\*.log;Views\**\*.*"/>
       <file include="Views\Home\**\*.cshtml" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>  

   <files>

       <file src="**\*.*" exclude="**\*.designer.cs;**\*.csproj;**\*.pdb;**\*.user;**\*.vspscc;**\*.nuspec;libman.json;package.json;packages.config;Web.config;ApplicationInsights.config;public\**\*.*;Resource\**\*.*;bin\**\*.*;node_modules\**\*.*;obj\**\*.*;**\*.log;Views\**\*.*"/>
       <file src="Views\Home\**\*.cshtml" />

   </files>
</package>
```

However, ALL of the views are still being included when I install the package in a different project.

I pack my package using the following command where `T:/` is my network share

```
nuget pack -Prop Configuration=Release -OutputDirectory T:/
```

Comment: What happens if you omit your second `<file>` tag so NO views are included?

Comment: @MattiPrice nothing changed! It's like the exclude list that I have is being ignored no matter what I have done

Comment: How are you installing the package? Also did you check in the package itself to see if the files are there? Just rename it to .zip and open it up.

Comment: So I did create a test project, and your nupsec file works fine and does what you want it to. So my guess is it is either an issue in how you are packaging it (where exactly is the .nupsec file in relation to the rest of the project?) or how you are installing the package which is somehow including some other stuff.

Comment: What is your project type .NET framework or .NET Core?

Comment: @MattiPrice I pack using the following command `nuget pack -Prop Configuration=Release -OutputDirectory T:/` where T is my network drive. Also, I renamed my package to `.zip` and extracted it to see what is in there, I see a folder called `content` that has all of my views not just the views in `Views/Home` folder. I am not sure why it worked for you but not for me. Also, my .nuspec file is located on the same level as my `csproj` file and my `Views` folder. Finally, my project is .NET 4.7.2 based not .Net Core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I exclude some views and folders from being included into the deployed ASP.NET MVC NuGet package?

The file element attribute `exclude` is correct attribute to exclude the files from the `src` location. But you missing another attribute `target`:

> The relative path to the folder within the package where the source
>   files are placed, which must begin with lib, content, build, or tools.

Check the document [File element attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#file-element-attributes) for some more details.

Otherwise, nuget package does not know where to put the files to the project when you install the package.

So, the .nuspec file should be like:

```
   <files>

       <file src="**\*.*" exclude="**\*.designer.cs;**\*.csproj;**\*.pdb;**\*.user;**\*.vspscc;**\*.nuspec;libman.json;package.json;packages.config;Web.config;ApplicationInsights.config;public\**\*.*;Resource\**\*.*;bin\**\*.*;node_modules\**\*.*;obj\**\*.*;**\*.log;Views\**\*.*" target="content\/>
       <file src="Views\Home\**\*.cshtml" target="content\Views\Home\" />

   </files>
```

But this package will add **all the files** into the the root folder of your installed project. Because you including all the file with wildcard `**\*.*`, Nuget could not to intelligently assign all of these files to the folder they should be in.

To resolve this issue, we should target files in different folders to different folders, like:

```
<file src="App_Start\*.cs" target="content\App_Start\" />
```

So, the `.nuspec` should be looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>TestWebApp</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Tester</authors>
    <owners>Tester</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>

  <files>
    <file src="App_Start\*.cs" target="content\App_Start\" />
    <file src="resources\*.*" target="content\resources\" />
     ....
    <file src="Views\Home\**\*.cshtml" target="content\Views\Home\" />
  </files>

</package>
```

Then pack this `.nuspec` file and install it into a Console App project to test:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally replicated your problem and figured out what it's doing. Basically `nuget pack` is looking at both your `.csproj` file and your `.nuspec` file. It includes everything in the `.csproj` file marked as `Build Action: Content` in your project. Which is why your views are showing up funny and files aren't being excluded properly.

So to fix it you have a couple options.

1) Change the build action in your project for those files to not be content (just use `None`)

2) Build the `.nuspec` file out to include all the files you need specifically like Leo's answer showed and then build with `nuget pack projectname.nuspec` to only pack based off of the `.nuspec` file ONLY

See this answer from some other details

[NuGet Pack: ignore default includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926186/nuget-pack-ignore-default-includes)